# Elementary combinatorial question

Tags: combinatorics

I've tried to solve the following exercise (Ross First Course 8th edition):

I have to chose three students from three groups of $n$ students (in total exist $3n$ students):

If I must choose two students of the same group and the other from a different class?
My try: First I chose a class of the three, then two students of that class, a class from two other class and finally an student:
$$3 \binom{n}{2} 2  \binom{n}{1}$$.

Then the next exercise is: If emphasized textthe three students must be in different classes
My try: $3 \binom{n}{1} 2 \binom{n}{1} 1 \binom{n}{1}$.
But the solution in the textbook is $n^3 = {\binom{n}{1}}^3$.

What's the difference?

Comment: Because you're choosing 3 groups you have $3\choose 3$$=1$ ways to choose 3 groups and n ways to select a student from each

Comment: But why in the first exercise I have to take in account the order? Or why first I can choose three and the two?

Comment: Because you can choose group ($1$ and $2$) or ($2$ and $3$) or ($1$ and $3$). While in the last one you can choose all groups in only one way.

Comment: To emphasize more when you write $3$ what is meant is $3 \choose 1$ because you are finding in how many ways can you get 1 group from 3. Now you are left with 2 groups and you want one of them that can be done in $2 \choose 1$ ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare these choices:

- Alice from class A,
- Bob from class B,
- Charlie from class C,

with

- Bob from class B,
- Charlie from class C,
- Alice from class A.

You've counted them as different choices, whereas the text considers them the same (the factor of $3 \times 2 \times 1$ represents the order in which the classes are chosen).

Comment: Sorry, but can explainme why in the first exercise if I choose two from a class $\binom{3

Comment: It's slightly different in the earlier case: Compare "Alice and Andrew from class A and Bob from class B" vs. "Alice from class A and Bob and Brenda from class B".  These are different.  I.e., choosing two things from class A and one from class B is different to choosing two things from class B and on from class A.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your solution is that $3n\cdot2n\cdot 1n$ implies that you care in which order you select the students: there is a first, a second, and a third.

So, this overcounts: choosing students A, B, and C is represented by the *orders* of choosing ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CAB, CBA.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're choosing $3$ groups you have $3\choose 3$$=1$ way to choose $3$ groups and $n$ ways to select a student from each. You get $3 \choose 3 $$n \times n \times n=n^3$. We don't multiply by $3$ and $2$ because we are not interested from what specific group that student comes from.